# View/Screen/Activity navigation in MVP

Tags: mvp

When using `MVP`, where should the logic of navigation be stored? Is it in `View` or is it in the `Presenter`?

Say `View1` (backed by a presenter `Presenter1`) has a button `PushMeToGo` somewhere in its view hierarchy. Said button should move the user from `View1` to `View2` when pressed.

Should the logic of moving into `View2` be handled directly inside `View1` or should it notify its presenter which will then execute the command instead?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked here 5 years ago: [In MVP, who should handle navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110536/in-mvp-who-should-handle-navigation) . Just let me make a little contribution. A view should be as dummy as possible containing no business logic at all (except of direct user interaction or, let's say, animation). Thus, the `View1.PushMeToGo` button could simply fire an event to notify the `Presenter1` that this button is pressed, and let the presenter delegate the navigation request to whatever that's responsible for navigatigating between views (let the presenter be as clean as possible). The V->P notification mechanism is on your own: an event bus, a simple observer, a single handler notified via `Presenter1.onPushMeToGoClicked` that's defined in the presenter interface as well. If you unit-test your code, this also lets you test the `onPushMeToGoClicked` handler having dummy views.